# I couldn't send message through instagram send message API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, facebook-javascript-sdk, instagram-graph-api

While calling send message api from postman using the page access token is giving an error message like:
`App does not have Advanced Access to instagram_manage_messages permission, and recipient user does not have role on app.`

The api which I called is

```
curl -i -X POST \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/LATEST-API-VERSION/me/messages?access_token=PAGE-ACCESS-TOKEN" \
  --data 'recipient={"id”:”IGSID”}&message={"text”:”TEXT-OR-LINK”}’
```

I'm using the page access token and the permission which I have given for creating the token are

> pages_manage_metadata,instagram_basic,instagram_manage_messages

As it is in developing stage I have given the facebook developer account a develepor role in the meta app.

Still I'm getting this error. What could be the issue. Could anybody help with it.

1. Tried reconnecting the instagram business account with the facebook page I'm using
2. Tried deleting the existing page and added new page

I couldn't get the desired result.

[Error details image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F8Gp.png)

Comment: _"As it is in developing stage I have given the facebook developer account a develepor role in the meta app."_ - which _one_ are you talking about here? The user who granted the page access token - or the recipient, as the message prompted?

Comment: I have given developer role for the user who granted the page token

Comment: You need to add the recipient as well, according to the error message.

Comment: I have tried that too but still getting the same exception. Don't know why